# Can a Plotly legend appear as annotations at the end of each line plot rather than in a box?

Tags: python, plotly

I was wonder if it possible for Plotly to have a legend for line plots to appear at the end of each line plot (see figure).

[image: Image of a line plot with legend at the end of each line]

I tried looking through the documentation but would not find anything specific about legends except that one can add annotations but they either overlap on top of each other and were to messy to place correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but it's not a legend at that point. You can use just words or use arrows and words.

Here's an example using data from a Plotly example. The tags are made with Plotly annotations. There are a TON of options when making these. They can be made dynamically, as well. (Versus one at a time like in my example.)

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
y = [0, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 6, 5]
y2 = [0, 4, 5, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2]

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = x, y = y))                       # make the graphs
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = x, y = y2))

fig.add_annotation(x = max(x) + .1, y = y[x.index(max(x))],   # add the tags
            text = "Germany", showarrow = False, xanchor = 'left')
fig.add_annotation(x = max(x) + .1, y = y2[x.index(max(x))],
            text = "Deutschland", showarrow = False, xanchor = 'left')
fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)                           # hide the legend

fig.show()
```

[image]

You can see a bunch of examples on [Plotly's site](https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Is there an effective way to avoid them overlapping? All I could do was check distances between annotations and nudge them to make space.

Comment: It looks like it's currently a feature request in Plotly.js. I can't think of a great way to resolve it off of the top of my head either.